# SKAction sequence is not delaying the spawnning of my nodes

Tags: swift, delay, skaction

I'm using an SKAction sequence to delay the spawning of my nodes under certain circumstances. When laneFire is true I do not want the delay to happen. But if else then I want the delay to happen. So I created an SKAction called spawnAction. Inside spawnAction I added the child. Then I put spawnAction inside my sequence. I put it after my waitAction in my sequence in order to create a delay before my node spawns. However, the spawning of my node is not delayed. It spawns on the screen and waits 1.5 seconds before performing moveAction.

Also, mouse! is an SKSpriteNode() and movingObjects is also an SKSpriteNode()

```
var action = SKAction()
    let spawnAction = SKAction(movingObjects.addChild(mouse!))
    let actionDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()

    if laneFire == true
    {
        action = SKAction.moveToY(self.size.height, duration: duration)

    }
    else
    {

        let waitAction = SKAction.waitForDuration(1.5)
        let moveAction = SKAction.moveToY(self.size.height, duration: duration)
        action = SKAction.sequence([waitAction, spawnAction, moveAction])

    }// end of laneFire if statement

    mouse!.runAction(SKAction.sequence([action, actionDone]))

    mouseCount++
```

Answer (score 0):

The following line is suspicious (I'm not sure why the compiler would accept it)

let spawnAction = SKAction(movingObjects.addChild(mouse!))

If mouse isn't initially hidden, it will immediately be added to the to the moving objects node and appear before the action is executed.

If you make your mouse node initially hidden, you could make spawnAction an unHide() :

```
mouse!.hidden = true
movingObjects.addChild(mouse!)
let spawnAction = SKAction.unHide()
...
```

Comment: I tried this but got an error. Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode = 0x0) .  I got this error on the line of code: mouse!.hidden = true. It says build succeeded but it stops and gives me this error.